# How can I view the raw PHP engine?

Tags: php

I'm interested in "looking under the hood" of PHP to see just how it works.

I have Apache and have been programing *using* PHP for years, but I'd like to see what makes it tick.

Comment: [Here's a link to instructions on obtaining the source code for PHP](http://ca3.php.net/git.php)

Comment: There are instructions on the PHP site on how to write an extension too, that should be helpful. I believe it explains how various var types are encoded and passed to C.

Comment: antother good stating point: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/03/phps-source-code-for-php-developers.html

Comment: The Vulcan Logic Dump ([VLD](http://pecl.php.net/package/vld)) is a good tool for looking at the bytecode that PHP generates

Comment: [**lxr.php.net**](http://lxr.php.net) ... I wouldn't be able to do **anything** with php-src if not for this tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the source on github:

https://github.com/php/php-src

(BTW: [Google is very helpful](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=php%20source&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8))

Comment: I did Google. They're very picky about phrasing these days...

Comment: That's my link, not mawburn's. And the third result is what I suggested.

Comment: @mawburn [It can be](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=ad6&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&channel=sb&q=view+php+engine&oq=view+php+engine&gs_l=serp.3..0i22i30l3.11141.12751.0.12864.9.8.0.0.0.0.158.913.2j6.8.0....0...1c.1.49.serp..1.8.906.1FJiQLGf7Lo)

Comment: I didn't complain about your question, is just answered it and added that you may could try google.